# Deciding on claims to prove grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm working on a homework assignment on designing and proving grammars, and I'm having a hard time deciding what claims to use in the proof of the design.  For example, I have a the problem of designing a grammar $G$ such that $L(G) = \{\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.  I've done this:

Let $x$ be a typical string: 
$x = \alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n$

With the following productions:

$S \rightarrow \alpha_0 A \\A \rightarrow \lambda | \alpha_1 A \alpha_2$

Which gives the grammar: $G = (\{S,A\}  \{\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2\}, S, \{S \rightarrow \alpha_0 A,\  A \rightarrow \lambda | \alpha_1 A \alpha_2\})$

At this point in the professors examples, he comes up with claims that I'm supposed to prove in order to prove that $L \subseteq L(G)$ and $L(G) \subseteq L$.  The only claim I can think of is $\forall n \ S \rightarrow^* \alpha_0 \alpha_1^n A \alpha_2^n$.

I have no idea if this claim is even useful, if there's more claims to solve, etc.  There's another 11 problems of this, so I'm looking to understand *how* to come up with claims rather than just the answer to this.

My new solution:

Claim 1
$ \forall n S \Rightarrow^* \alpha_0 \alpha_1^n A \alpha_2^n $

Proof Claim 1

Base Case $n=0$: 
$ S \Rightarrow^* \alpha_0 \alpha_1^0 A \alpha_2^0 = \alpha_0 A $

Inductive Hypothesis: $\forall n \ S\Rightarrow^* \alpha_0 \alpha_1^n A \alpha_2^n$

Inductive Step $n=n+1$:
$S \Rightarrow^* \alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_1 A \alpha_2 \alpha_2^n = \alpha_0 \alpha_1^{n+1} A \alpha_2^{n+1}  $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use *induction on the length of the derivation*. Your claim goes in that direction. In your case things are relatively simple, because the grammar is linear and there is only one path to follow. So in $n+1$ steps you can derive $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n$ and $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n A \alpha_2^n$.

This can be proven by induction starting from $n=1$. All the words that are generated are thus of the form $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n$ and in the desired language.

The inverse inclusion (all words of the generated language are generated by at least one derivation) is quite clear in this case: for $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n$ briefly descibe the $n+1$-step derivation, if you want to do it in a very complete and correct manner.

Comment: So far, when I do induction it's that at every step (base case, inductive hypothesis, and inductive step), I have to come up to some predefined equality.  I'm confused on what the equality needs to be?  Is it just the claim that I made?

Comment: You have probably done inductions on arithmetic equations. But you can do it on any statement that contains an integer. Here it is: "In n+1 steps the grammar derives exactly the strings $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n \alpha_2^n$ and $\alpha_0 \alpha_1^n A \alpha_2^n$."  You prove it for a base case and then show the step from $n+1$ to $n+2$ (by explaining the possibilities for the n+2nd step and their effects on the string). With this, the statement is proven in general, and thus you have proven that the grammar generates only terminal strings from the desired language.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense now.  So the general claims for these kinds of grammars is "It derives to a terminal string if n = 0 or 1" and "It derives to a non terminal string for which I have a production"? If so then I think I get it now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, partially yes. But it is important that all of the derived terminal strings are of the form desired. This is to prove $L(G)\subseteq L$.

Comment: Alright, so with this, I tried it again with a new claim.  I edited the original post with it.  It seems right to me, but I'm unsure.

Comment: It is important to use $\Rightarrow^n$ instead of $\Rightarrow^*$ - otherwise you are not necessarily speaking about $n$ steps. And in $0$ steps ypu do not derive anything. Your base case is already "one step"; also the following $n$ need to be one higher to derive the corresponding strings. Other than that it looks fine, maybe addsome explanation on which rule is applied where, though in this case it is almost obvious.